# How to get value by FieldName in a Flink Row?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a method `def process(row: org.apache.flink.types.Row, fieldName: String) : Unit = ???`

And the processing I want to do requires me to extract a field by the name of `fieldName`. I can see that the Row api allows you to extract by order, but not by name.

I guess the users will have to pass me schema information, so the method will look like `def process(row: org.apache.flink.types.Row, rowSchema: ???, fieldName: String) : Unit = ???`.

I've looked into `org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.RowType` and `TypeInformation` for the schema information but neither of them seem right. What's the best way to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I need `org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.RowTypeInfo`. It has method `getFieldIndex(String fieldName)`